# SAS How do i create a counter to decrease on variable change rules

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble trying to get a counting variable to decreased based on the rules of other variables given to me by a client.

currently, i have the "HAVE" column, but want to achieve the "WANT"

we know there are 5 unique date changed for this ID, and ignoring the duplicate value on the same day - this would then show my i have 5 unique value changes over time.

here is an example, HAVE is my attempt, where WANT is the desired outcome (i think).

```
 DATA HAVE;
    LENGTH
        ID 8 DATE_OF_VALUE $10 VALUE 8 HAVE 8 WANT 8 ;
    FORMAT
        ID 9. DATE_OF_VALUE $10. VALUE 5. HAVE 1. WANT 1. ;
    INFORMAT
        ID 9. DATE_OF_VALUE $10. VALUE 5. HAVE 1. WANT 1. ;
    INFILE DATALINES4
        DLM=','
        MISSOVER
        DSD ;
    INPUT
        ID : 9. DATE_OF_VALUE : $10. VALUE: 5. HAVE: 1.WANT : 1. ;
DATALINES4;
109999999,05/12/2017,42376,1,5
109999999,05/12/2017,42376,2,.
109999999,13/12/2017,42521,1,4
109999999,13/12/2017,42521,2,.
109999999,19/03/2018,43395,1,3
109999999,19/03/2018,43395,2,.
109999999,19/03/2018,43395,3,.
109999999,19/03/2018,43395,4,.
109999999,04/06/2018,43953,1,2
109999999,04/06/2018,43953,2,.
109999999,17/09/2018,44899,1,1
109999999,17/09/2018,44899,2,.
109999998,21/04/2018,4788,1,2
109999998,21/04/2018,4788,2,.
109999998,01/06/2018,4788,3,.
109999998,01/06/2018,4788,4,.
109999998,23/09/2018,4718,1,1
109999998,23/09/2018,4718,2,.
109999997,09/07/2018,8717,1,2
109999997,09/07/2018,8717,2,.
109999997,01/09/2018,8750,1,1
109999997,01/09/2018,8750,2,.
109999995,15/02/2018,22868,1,2
109999995,15/02/2018,22868,2,.
109999995,07/09/2018,22631,1,1
109999995,07/09/2018,22631,2,.
109554995,05/12/2017,92376,1,5
109554995,05/12/2017,92376,2,.
109554995,13/12/2017,92521,1,4
109554995,13/12/2017,92521,2,.
109554995,19/03/2018,93395,1,3
109554995,19/03/2018,93395,2,.
109554995,19/03/2018,93395,3,.
109554995,19/03/2018,93395,4,.
109554995,04/06/2018,93953,1,2
109554995,04/06/2018,93953,2,.
109554995,11/07/2018,94953,1,1
;;;;
```

Comment: Please update your question to show what code you have tried, and describe whether you are getting an error or unexpected results.

Comment: the code i tried is what give me the HAVE column but is incorrect

Comment: `data TEST1;
 set TEST;

 by ID VALUE DATE_OF_VALUE;

 if first.VALUE and first.DATE_OF_VALUE then do;
 HAVE=1;
 end;

 else do ;
 HAVE+1;
 end;


run;`

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not in the comments. trying to read code in comments is painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is with what is known as a double DOW loop.

You read the data in ID groups, twice.  You'll see two do loops in the code.  The first reads the records in an ID group to count the number of unique dates.  The second then re-reads the same records, and outputs it record with a decremented counter.

Note that in my HAVE I read your date_of_value variable as a numeric date variable, so that it would be sorted.  If you want to leave it as character, you could add a proc sort step.

```
data want ;

  *Count the number of distinct for an ID group; 
  do until (last.id) ;
    set have (keep=ID Date_Of_Value Value rename=(Date_Of_value=Date));
    by descending id date  ;
    if first.date then _DateCount=sum(_DateCount,1) ;
  end ;

  *Re-read the records for the ID group, decrementing the counter and outputting ;

  do until(last.id) ;
    set have (keep=ID Date_Of_Value Value rename=(Date_Of_value=Date));
    by descending id date  ;
    if first.id then Want=_DateCount ;
    else if first.date then Want=Want-1 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

This gives repeated values of WANT within a buy group, which is different than your WANT where you have missing values after WANT on repeated dates:

```
    ID        Date    VALUE    Wan

109999999    21158    42376      5
109999999    21158    42376      5
109999999    21166    42521      4
109999999    21166    42521      4
109999999    21262    43395      3
109999999    21262    43395      3
109999999    21262    43395      3
109999999    21262    43395      3
109999999    21339    43953      2
109999999    21339    43953      2
109999999    21444    44899      1
109999999    21444    44899      1
109999998    21295     4788      3
109999998    21295     4788      3
109999998    21336     4788      2
109999998    21336     4788      2
109999998    21450     4718      1
109999998    21450     4718      1
109999997    21374     8717      2
109999997    21374     8717      2
109999997    21428     8750      1
109999997    21428     8750      1
109999995    21230    22868      2
109999995    21230    22868      2
109999995    21434    22631      1
109999995    21434    22631      1
109554995    21158    92376      5
109554995    21158    92376      5
109554995    21166    92521      4
109554995    21166    92521      4
109554995    21262    93395      3
109554995    21262    93395      3
109554995    21262    93395      3
109554995    21262    93395      3
109554995    21339    93953      2
109554995    21339    93953      2
109554995    21376    94953      1
```

I tend to dislike missing values, but you're free to update this to create missings if you want. : )